# How to create rewrite rules to transform subdirectories into query strings

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'd like to take this:

```
www.example.com/query/bla/anotherquery/bla2/thirdquery/bla3
```

and have it interpreted dynamically as this:

```
www.example.com/index.php?query=bla&anotherquery=bla2&thirdquery=bla3
```

In the httpd-vhost.conf with mod-rewrite functions

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "/Users/me/Sites/Development"
    ServerName development
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteRule ?
</VirtualHost>
```

I'd also like `http://www.example.com/index.php` to resolve to `http://www.example.com/`

Is this possible? Unsafe? How would I do this? I'm using PHP and mac local server with apache.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this recursive rule for this in your root .htaccess:

```
DirectoryIndex index.php
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]*)(/.*)?$ $3?$1=$2 [L,QSA]
```